# Op-amp feedback and stability

Tags: operational-amplifier, mosfet, circuit-analysis, feedback, stability

I have 2 questions related to this circuit.
[image]

**1**
The first question concerns the open-loop gain. I am tasked with finding both the open-loop and closed-loop gain. The closed-loop gain is calculated using the formula CL gain = A / (1 + BA), where A represents the open-loop gain and B was previously calculated by me.

Earlier, I was required to determine the load effect of the feedback on the open-loop circuit. I performed the analysis using both sampling and mixing in voltage. The circuit is shown below.

I used that circuit to attempt finding the open-loop gain, but I am encountering difficulty establishing the connection between 'vs' and the output.

[image]
Since

**M1 AND M3:**
[image]

**M2 AND M4:**
[image]

I figured since both source and gate of M2 are conected to the ground (in open loop), MOSFET 2 is only going to be represent by Ro in parallel with Rob. And M4 is a resistor of 1/gm in parallel with ro, because the gate is connected to the drain. Given that, I don't understand how I am supposed to get Vg3 in order to find vo (because once I have Vg3 I also have vg5, and from there I can calculate vo). There is no current source to find any voltage of M2 and M4.

**2**
My second question is about the stability of the op-amp.
I am asked to find the positions of the first and second poles of the amplifier in open loop, ignoring the time constants of the input loops.
They say to take this picture and expressions as a reference.

I dont really understand what is asked here. By position of the poles, they mean finding the final value of wp1 and wp2?
If so, the only job is really the math right?

Any help is welcome :)

[image]

Comment: Why not use a simulator?

Comment: @Andyaka I tried to simulate on LTSpice but dind't get any conclusions. I don't understand how the math is done here.